# Call a method recursive on java beans with refelection

Tags: java, reflection

i've got the following problem:
There are java beans of that kind:

```java
public abstract class BaseModel {
  public void doSomeThing(int x) {
    // Do cool stuff here with x
  }
}

public class ModelA extends BaseModel {
}

public class ModelB extends BaseModel {
   private ModelA modelA;
   private OtherStuff otherStuff;
}
```

I'm searching now a way to call all BaseModel.doSomeThing(int x) methods on my object tree. The model is under my control, so if its needed I can modifiy it.

**EDIT**: here hopefully a bit clearer what I try to achive: I want to provide the base class BaseModel. Users then extend their classes from this base class. I want to provide a class with a method doStuff(BaseModel model) which calls doSomeThing(x) on every instance of BasseModel in the provided object tree of the BaseModel instance.

Example:

```java
ClassToBeFound classToBeFound = new ClassToBeFound();
ModelB modelB = new ModelB();
classToBeFound.magicMethod(modelB, 10);
// this should lead to a call of modelB.doSomeThing(10) and modelB.modelA.doSomeThing(10)
```

Since I do not know about the concrete object graph of the object passed to magicMethod, I need a way to find out wich instances of BaseModel are in the graph.

Regards

Daniel

Comment: What's the problem? What have you tried and why didn't it work?

Comment: You need to call `doSomeThing(int x)` in all your Entities?

Comment: Could you provide your *object tree*?

Comment: Your question is very unclear.  Please add an example of what you want to do.